# Не могу разобраться с постраничной навигацией

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache

Здравствуйте. Хочу на странице вывести определенное кол-во статей, например 10. 
Если всего статей в бозе более 10, то на странице выводим только 10 статей, и делаем постраничную навигацию, чтоб можно было листать странички и просматривать остальные статьи.

Вывожу статьи вот так:

```
$set_coll_page = '10'; //кол-во статей на страницу
$kolvo_page=k_page($coll,$set_coll_page);
$page=page($kolvo_page);
$otkuda=$set_coll_page*$page-$set_coll_page;


$tovariall = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tovari` WHERE `id_cat` = '$directID[id]' ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT $otkuda, $set_coll_page");
while ($tall = mysql_fetch_assoc($tovariall)) {
//разметка
}

if ($kolvo_page>1)navigation('?',$kolvo_page,$page); //выводим навигацию по страницам
```

Сама функция навигации:

```
function page($k_page=1){
$page=1;
if (isset($_GET['page'])){
if ($_GET['page']=='end')$page=intval($k_page);elseif(is_numeric($_GET['page'])) $page=intval($_GET['page']);}
if ($page<1)$page=1;
if ($page>$k_page)$page=$k_page;
return $page;
}



function k_page($kol_foto=0,$k_p_str=10){
if ($kol_foto!=0){$v_pages=ceil($kol_foto/$k_p_str);return $v_pages;}
else return 1;
}


function navigation($link='?',$k_page=1,$page=1){
if ($page<1)$page=1;
echo "<div class='trazdp4'>\n";
if ($page!=1)echo "<a href=\"".$link."page=1\"><span class=\"pbt1\">&lt;&lt;</a> </span>";
echo " ";
if ($page!=1)echo "<span class=\"pbt2\"><a href=\"".$link."page=1\">1</a></span>";else echo "<b>1</b>";
for ($ot=-3; $ot<=3; $ot++){
if ($page+$ot>1 && $page+$ot<$k_page){
if ($ot==-3 && $page+$ot>2)echo " ...";
if ($ot!=0)echo " <a href=\"".$link."page=".($page+$ot)."\"><span class=\"pbt2\">".($page+$ot)."</span></a>";else echo " <b>".($page+$ot)."</b>";
if ($ot==3 && $page+$ot<$k_page-1)echo " ...";}}
if ($page!=$k_page)echo " <a href=\"".$link."page=end\"><span class=\"pbt2\">$k_page</span></a>";elseif ($k_page>1)echo " <b>$k_page</b>";
if ($page!=$k_page)echo " <a href=\"".$link."page=end\"><span class=\"pbt1\">&gt;&gt;</span></a>";
echo "</span></div>";
}
```

И это все работает, НО есть одна пролемка - у меня в .htaccess задано правило, для адреса странички со статьями: **RewriteRule ^tovari/(.+)$ modules/catalog/tovari.php?url=$1**

и если зайти по ссылке: мой.сайт/tovari/statii-pro-myso и пробовать листать странички - листинг не работает, тупо показывает первые 10 статей.

А вот есои перейти на статьи по ссылке: мой.сайт/modules/catalog/tovari.php?url=statii-pro-myso  - листинг работает как нужно!

В чем может быть проблема?
Буду благодарен за любую полезную информацию!

Comment: Если ввести ссылку так: мой.сайт/tovari/statii-pro-myso&page=2 - листинг работает, но не сама нумерация страниц висит на первой

Comment: вы уверены что ссылки у вас верные?.перейди в первом варианте (мой.сайт/tovari/statii-pro-myso) по ссылке с навигации и во втором варианте (мой.сайт/modules/catalog/tovari.php) и вставьте полный URL сюда с обоих случаев..

Comment: @LesyukAlexey 1: /tovari/podkategorija-stulja&page=2 2: /modules/catalog/tovari.php?url=podkategorija-stulja&page=2

Comment: @LesyukAlexey изначально я так и делал. в таком случае вообще навигация не работает. только стоят номера страниц и при переходе на, например, вторую страницу, ничего не изменяется, то есть выводит первые 10 статей

Comment: @LesyukAlexey **Notice: Undefined index: page ** , если ссылка /tovari/podkategorija-stulja?page=2 тогда вообще параметр **page** не определяет

Comment: отписал в комментах ниже..

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40404/discussion-between-lesyuk-alexey-and-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код неважный, ябы переписал его полностью.....ответ на ваш вопрос ниже...

ЧПУ также не рекомендую так делать....делайте через одну точку входа в .htaccess  ..тогда не нужно будет что либо в будущем вообще писать в .htaccess для любой страницы которая нуждается в ЧПУ.

замените

```
function navigation($link='?',$k_page=1,$page=1){
```

на

```
function navigation($link='?',$k_page=1,$page=1){
$basePath = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 0, strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '&'));
```

замените

```
if ($kolvo_page>1)navigation('?',$kolvo_page,$page);
```

на

```
if ($kolvo_page>1)navigation('&',$kolvo_page,$page);
```

замените

```
if ($ot!=0)echo " <a href=\"".$link."page=".($page+$ot)."\"><span class=\"pbt2\">".($page+$ot)."</span></a>";else echo " <b>".($page+$ot)."</b>";
if ($ot==3 && $page+$ot<$k_page-1)echo " ...";}}
if ($page!=$k_page)echo " <a href=\"".$link."page=end\"><span class=\"pbt2\">$k_page</span></a>";elseif ($k_page>1)echo " <b>$k_page</b>";
if ($page!=$k_page)echo " <a href=\"".$link."page=end\"><span class=\"pbt1\">&gt;&gt;</span></a>";
```

на

```
if ($ot!=0)echo " <a href=\"$basePath".$link."page=".($page+$ot)."\"><span class=\"pbt2\">".($page+$ot)."</span></a>";else echo " <b>".($page+$ot)."</b>";
if ($ot==3 && $page+$ot<$k_page-1)echo " ...";}}
if ($page!=$k_page)echo " <a href=\"$basePath".$link."page=end\"><span class=\"pbt2\">$k_page</span></a>";elseif ($k_page>1)echo " <b>$k_page</b>";
if ($page!=$k_page)echo " <a href=\"$basePath".$link."page=end\"><span class=\"pbt1\">&gt;&gt;</span></a>";
```

Comment: изначально я так и делал. в таком случае вообще навигация не работает. только стоят номера страниц и при переходе на, например, вторую страницу, ничего не изменяется, то есть выводит первые 10 статей

Comment: ставьте вопрос в конце URL,  будем разбираться в проблеме....и замените $kolvo_page=k_page($coll,$set_coll_page);  на $kolvo_page=k_page($coll,$set_coll_page);echo "kolvo_page=".$kolvo_page;  а также $page=page($kolvo_page); на $page=page($kolvo_page); echo "page=".$page;   что вывелось на экран?

Comment: но это весь код который отвечает за вывод статей и навигацию, больше нету

Comment: в таком случае не выводит статьи, так как они у меня берутся из определенной категории. категория определяется по $_GET['url'] - в нашем случае это *podkategorija-stulja* , и если добавить **/** , в таком случае категорию не видит

Comment: давайте с начала начнем выяснять, что выводят echo те что выше я написал?

Comment: только что посетила мысль. кажется передавать параметр **page** мне нужно именно через & , так как этот символ служит для разделения параметров, первый параметр у меня url ,  в .htaccess : RewriteRule ^tovari/(.+)$ modules/catalog/tovari.php?url=$1 что думаете?

Comment: думаю что не нада забегать вперед..ответьте на предыдущий вопрос...

Comment: Так эта функция работает если не переходить по ссылке указанной в правиле хтаццесс

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40405/discussion-between--and-lesyuk-alexey).

Comment: извиняюсь, не совсем понял куда добавить **добавьте $basePath тут**

Comment: подставил все. но номер страницы по прежнему не показвает

Comment: что за номер страницы? вопрос был в том что листинг не показывало..